# Pandas: How to use get_group() with a groupby() based on a function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I adapted one example from [Pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-sorting):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Y' : [1, 4, 3, 2]})

df3.groupby(['X', 'Y']).get_group(('A', 1))
    X   Y
0   A   1
```

The code above works fine.

Now I want to group the samples based on the value of a function:

```
def func(df, index):
    return (df['X'].loc[index], df['Y'].loc[index] % 2)
```

The grouping works:

```
for name, df in df3.groupby(by=lambda index: func(df3, index), sort=False):
    print(name)
    print(df)

('A', 1)
   X  Y
0  A  1
2  A  3

('B', 0)
   X  Y
1  B  4
3  B  2
```

But get_group() returns an error:

```
df3.groupby(by=lambda index: func(df3, index), sort=False).get_group(('A', 1))
```

> NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex

I could iterate through the groupby and save the keys/values in a dictionary to access the groups by name, but that would be inefficient memory-wise.

Comment: I can't reproduce, this works for me with the data you've provided (Pandas v0.19.2).

Comment: @jpp That's not good news. I am using pandas==0.21.1 and I can reproduce in a fresh install.

Comment: @jpp: and I also confirm that a fresh install with pandas==0.19 does NOT reproduce the issue.

Comment: I reported an issue on Pandas' github tracker: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22257